# expo push notifications not working in android apk

Tags: typescript, firebase, expo

It's a question about notifications in expo, I have create my android apk with eas on react native. So I can send and receive notifications in expo go, but its not the same in the created apk, i can see the expopushtoken and i can send messages but, but im not receiving the message,
I have the granted permission and the expo push token:
`LOG  granted`
`LOG  ExponentPushToken[GwCamMJoK0l1kXOBjNEsxa]`

I hope the apk will receive notifications, any configuration needed